# Palindrome code looks fine but I can't get it to run

Tags: javascript, string, visual-studio, palindrome

I am doing a palindrome coder challenge and I am very new to coding. I cannot get it to run right to save my life. I had someone look at it and they said it should be fine but obviously, something isn't right. I have tried various small changes, updating in VS each time and nothing seems to work.

```
    $('#bntCrunch').on("click", function () {

        var str = $('input').val()
        function pal() {
            const reversed = str
                .split('')
                .reverse()
                .join('');

            return str === reversed;

            if (str == reversed) {
                document.getElementById('output').innerHTML(str);
            }

            else {
                document.getElementById('output').innerHTML("That is not a palindrome");
            }
        }
    })

</script>
```

VS seems to say "pal has been defined but its value is never read" no matter where I call the function.

Comment: You have a function `pal()` which needs to be invoked for it to run. Your code isn't invoking/calling it, it is only creating/declaring the function. Using `return` in a function will stop the function execution, so the code below the return in the function will not get executed

Comment: call function  `var str = $('input').val(); pal() `

Answer (score 0):

Watch out, if you want to be case insensitive, you'll have to add ".toLowerCase()" on each side of the "===" test.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $( "#button" ).on( "click", function() {
    $('#result').text($('#test').val()===$('#test').val().split('').reverse().join('')?"OK":"KO");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="test" />
<input type="button" id="button" value="Test" />
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are already returning a boolean value in pal() function; this return str === reversed; you don't want to have that there.

also, remember to invoke the pal()